# JavaScript - setInterval with passed function does not recognize global variables

Tags: javascript, scope, callback, function-pointers, setinterval

I was stuck in some weird problem and then the problem got a challenge to understand why Angular behaves like this, there was *no much luck* searching at Google for the problem, so I am here.

I wanted to test `setInterval()` function and counter some variable, not something too hard, and I got stuck in problem that I couldn't find solution for or explaination.

This is my code I am using and it works fine:

```
public counter: number = 1;

  myFunction() {
    setInterval(() => {
      console.log(this.counter);
      this.counter++;
    }, 1000);
  }

Output: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5...
```

This code works fine, but when I am taking the function to be like this, I get undefined as output and then `Nan, Nan, Nan`.

```
public counter: number = 1;

  foo() {
    console.log(this.counter);
    this.counter++;
  }

  myFunction() {
    setInterval(this.foo, 1000);
  }

* myFunction is the starting function *

Output: undefined, Nan, Nan, Nan...
```

I guess there is some problem with variables access that foo() cannot access the global variables, but how is that happening? and how can I fix this problem?

Comment: `setInterval(() => this.foo(), ...)` or `setInterval(this.foo.bind(this), ...)` or ... This is nothing to do with Angular/TS/ES6, see any JS `this` scoping question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

here's a code that acts as you discribed

```
 class A{
 public counter: number = 1;

   foo() {
     alert(this.counter);
     this.counter++;
   }

   myFunction() {
     setInterval(this.foo, 1000);
   }
 }

 const a = new A();
 a.myFunction(); // output andefined, Nan, Nan ...
```

now the code using **bind** : [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0t2uy47m/)

```
 class A{
 public counter: number = 1;

   foo() {
     alert(this.counter);
     this.counter++;
   }

   myFunction() {
     setInterval(this.foo.bind(this), 1000);
   }
 }

 const a = new A();
 a.myFunction(); // output 1, 2, 3, 4 ...
```

this is a very tricky subject so

first check this question [How to access the correct 'this' inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback/38931751)

and couple of insanely good answer about the subject [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20279485/8385466) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38931751/8385466) .

---

**now the bind method - [Function.prototype.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) :**

(from the docs)

> The `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

and loved this expletetion (took from the Examples part in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)) :

> The simplest use of `bind()` is to make a function that, no matter how it is called, is called with a particular `this` value.
>
> A common mistake for new JavaScript programmers is to extract a method from an object, then to later call that function and expect it to use the original object as its `this` (e.g. by using that method in callback-based code).
>   Without special care, however, the original object is usually lost.
>
> Creating a bound function from the function, using the original object, neatly solves this problem

Answer (score 2):

In the first example you are passing a function declared in es6 shorthand (link [here](https://derickbailey.com/2015/09/28/do-es6-arrow-functions-really-solve-this-in-javascript/)), therefore `"this"` will be bound to the current scope.

In the second example you are passing a reference to a function and because `setTimeout` executes the function with this pointing to the global object, `"this"` equals the window object and therefore the properties are undefined.